# How can a default interface method call a method of its super object? (e.g. clone)

Tags: java, clone

I would like to provide in an interface a default implementation of `clone()` that calls the `super.clone()` of `Object`.

Yet, that is not possible and gives the error: `super reference is illegal in interface context`.

One possible alternative is to use an `abstract class` which works fine for that purpose. Yet, it will impose some limitations on multiple inheritance. Hence, an interface would work better in that scenario.

So, to maintain the interface option, I can take a workaround and call `super.clone()` via reflection, despite being awkward, such as:

```java
try {
  Method methodClone = Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("clone");
  methodClone.setAccessible(true);
  return (A) methodClone.invoke(this);
} catch(NoSuchMethodException |IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

It works, but with warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by ... to method java.lang.Object.clone()
```

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without an abstract class. Interfaces by design cannot have method bodies.

Comment: @zmehall interfaces may have `default` methods that can have bodies.

Comment: put clone() in the interface.  Any implementor will have it

Answer (score 2):

> would like to provide in an interface a default implementation of clone() that calls the super.clone() of Object
> Yet, that is not possible and gives the error: super reference is
> illegal in interface context.

The reason this is not possible and should not be possible is simple.

`Classes` are allowed to extend only 1 parenting class. Therefore they can call `super()` since the parent class could be determined as a single class.

`Interfaces` on the other side are allowed to extend multiple parenting interfaces. Therefore the call to `super()` will not be able to be determined as to which parenting interface it relates to.

If you are curious to know why java was designed like this you can take a read [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-diamond-problem-in-java) the popular *Java diamond problem*